# How to add word Chapter number before Chapter title

Tags: formatting, koma-script, scrbook

I am writing thesis. I want to add "Chapter Number" before the Chapter title at the start of each chapter.For example Chapter 1 followed by Chapter title in next line. In Table of contents it should remain as it is shown in MWE below.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
\documentclass[oneside,12pt ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{cite}

\linespread{1.5}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%\chapter{Acknowledgements}

%\chapter{Abstract}
%A brief summary of the thesis goes here.
\mainmatter
\chapter {Introduction}
Introduction
\chapter{ Literature Review}


\backmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{myBib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded at the end of the preamble in 99% of all cases, not right at the start!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Add option `chapterprefix` or `headings=chapterwithprefixline`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,
  chapterprefix% <- add this option
]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter
\chapter {Introduction}
Introduction
\chapter{ Literature Review}
\end{document}
```

[image]