# How to personalize the prefix of chapter title(Header)

Tags: sectioning

I would like to add the key word chapter before the number for the chapter title. I am using the following template for a [thesis](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis).
for example, the first chapter is test, `\chapter{test}`
This show the following header         "1 Test"
The change I want make the header as following      "Chapter 1:
                                                    Test" and I think that the following is the code to be change (the cls file from the template above):

```
 %  Simple interface for the user  to customize the chapter titles 
    \ProvideDocumentCommand{\abovechapterskip}{}{\vspace*{20pt}}
    \ProvideDocumentCommand{\chapterbelowskip}{}{\vspace*{40pt}}
    \ProvideDocumentCommand{\chapterinbetweenskip}{}{\vspace*{20pt}}
    \ProvideDocumentCommand{\autodot}{}{}
    \ProvideDocumentCommand{\mdtChapapp}{}{}
    \ProvideDocumentCommand{\chapteralign}{}{\raggedright}
    \ProvideDocumentCommand{\chapterfont}{}{\Huge\bfseries}
    \ProvideDocumentCommand{\chapterprefixfont}{}{\LARGE\bfseries}
    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\@makechapterhead}{ m }{%
        \abovechapterskip
        {\parindent \z@ \chapteralign \normalfont
            \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \if@mainmatter
            \ifbool{chapteroneline}{%
                \chapterfont \mdtChapapp\thechapter\autodot\enspace
            }{%
                \chapterprefixfont \@chapapp\space \thechapter
                \par\nobreak
                \chapterinbetweenskip
            }%
            \fi
            \fi
            \interlinepenalty\@M%
            \chapterfont #1\par\nobreak
            \chapterbelowskip
        }
        \thispagestyle{\chapter@p@gestyle}
    }
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
        \abovechapterskip
        {\parindent \z@ \chapteralign
            \normalfont
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \chapterfont  #1\par\nobreak
            \chapterbelowskip
        }
        \thispagestyle{\chapter@p@gestyle}
    }


% Addchap provides unnumbered chapters with an entry in the table of contents as well as an updated header
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\addchap}{ s o m }{%
    \chapter*{#3}%
    \markboth{}{}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    }{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
            \addchaptertocentry{#3}%
            \markboth{\MakeMarkcase{#3}}{\MakeMarkcase{#3}}%
        }{%
            \addchaptertocentry{#2}%
            \markboth{\MakeMarkcase{#2}}{\MakeMarkcase{#2}}%
        }%
    }%
}%

\ProvideDocumentCommand{\addsec}{ s o m }{%
    \section*{#3}%
    \markright{}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    }{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#3}%
            \markright{\MakeMarkcase{#3}}%%
        }{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
            \markright{\MakeMarkcase{#2}}%
        }%
    }%
}%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which documentclass do you use? Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you currently produce your document?

Comment: [How to add word Chapter number before Chapter title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346080/134144)  could be interesting.

Comment: Where does the code you added to your question come from? Please add a complete minimal working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to comment `chapterinoneline` option